# unable to run executable after cx_freeze, numpy deleting sys

Tags: python, linux, numpy, chmod, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an .exe file for my simple game programmed in Python. From within python it runs, when I build it and try to open .exe, I get the following error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "snakegame.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 346, in <module>
    import pygame.surfarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/surfarray.py", line 72, in <module>
    import pygame._numpysurfarray as numpysf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/_numpysurfarray.py", line 51, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from .core import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sys'
```

From this discussion
https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2013-February/065596.html
 I try to edit my `/numpy/core/__init__.py`, namely deleting the line `del sys` at the end. However it does not help and I get the same error trying to run .exe. What can be the solution?

Comment: Do you have superuser privileges? And is this on Linux?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh yes, i just managed to edit file after sudo chmod 777 ... -- however it does not solve the problem with running the .exe. what can be the solution?

Comment: Did you remove the delete sys line? I've successfully gotten it to work with PyInstaller and cxFreeze doing so.

And upon deleting that line, what's  the error trace if it doesn't work?